# Какая-то проблема с формами

Tags: python, django, forms

Я уже весь день долблюсь с этими формами, а дедлайн по школьному проекту уже завтра... Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

```html
<div class="right_bottom_top_right">
                  <form action="" method="post">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                        <p>Интеграция (в рублях):</p>
                        {% if on_site.price_for_integration is None %}
                            {{ form_prices.price_for_integration }}
                        {% else %}
                            {{ on_site.price_for_integration }}
                        {% endif %}
                        <p>Рекламный ролик (в рублях):</p>
                        {% if on_site.price_per_mention is None %}
                            {{ form_prices.price_per_mention }}
                        {% else %}
                            {{ on_site.price_per_mention }}
                        {% endif %}
                        <p>Упомянание (в рублях):</p>
                        {% if on_site.price_per_commercial is None %}
                            {{ form_prices.price_per_commercial }}
                        {% else %}
                            {{ on_site.price_per_commercial }}
                        {% endif %}
                      <p><button type="submit"> Отправить</button> </p>
                  </form>
              </div>
```

вот проблемная часть кода html (файл profile.html)
он выводит какую-то фигню вместо полей для ввода:
[image: какая-то фигня]

вот файл forms.py:

```
class InformationForProfile(forms.Form):
    price_for_integration = forms.CharField(max_length=255),
    price_per_mention = forms.CharField(max_length=255),
    price_per_commercial = forms.CharField(max_length=255),


class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file_video = forms.FileField(label='Видео')
```

вот views.py:

```
def profile(request):
    user_now = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            form_prices = InformationForProfile(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                fp = Bloger.objects.get(pk=user_now.channel_id_id)
                fp.video1 = form.cleaned_data['file_video']
                fp.save()
                # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:profile'))
            if form_prices.is_valid():
                fp = Bloger.objects.get(pk=user_now.channel_id_id)
                fp.price_for_integration = form_prices.cleaned_data['price_for_integration']
                fp.price_per_mention = form_prices.cleaned_data['price_per_mention']
                fp.price_per_commercial = form_prices.cleaned_data['price_per_commercial']
                fp.save()
                # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:profile'))
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
            form_prices = InformationForProfile()
        data = Bloger.objects.get(pk=user_now.channel_id_id)
        on_site = {}
        on_site['channel_id'] = data.channel_id
        on_site['title'] = data.title
        on_site['platform'] = data.platform
        on_site['views_median'] = data.views_median
        on_site['views_count'] = data.views_count
        on_site['sub_count'] = data.sub_count
        on_site['description'] = data.description

        on_site['price_for_integration'] = data.price_for_integration
        on_site['price_per_mention'] = data.price_per_mention
        on_site['price_per_commercial'] = data.price_per_commercial
        on_site['video1'] = data.video1

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html',
                  {'on_site': on_site,
                   'form': form,
                   'form_prices': form_prices,
                   }
                  )
```

хочу заметить, что форма UploadFileForm почти такая же, и вьюха для нее очень похожа, однако она работает адекватно. Также хочу отметить, что когда-то, ещё утром, и InformationForProfile работала не так как мне надо, но хотя бы выводила поля для ввода, но после того, как я что-то изменил, она слетела.
Подскажите, пожалуйста (очень желательно сегодня). Спасибо

Comment: `(max_length=255),` — запятые поубирайте

Comment: @andreymal Капец, столько часов пытался разобраться в чём проблема, а она в запятых....... Спасибо огромное

Comment: и еще, слово "Упоминание" пишется через "и".